# Adding up to text javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I want to add to existing text based on the input user provide,

below is what I am trying to reach

```
<html>
<p>Enter the IDs of devices seperated by comma</p>
<input id="devicesIDs"></input>
```

```
<script> 
            function ButtonClicked(devicesIDs): 
            var IDs = document.getElementById("devicesIDs").innerText;
            var inputArray = IDs.split(',');

            let obj = {
        "c8y_isDynamicGroup": {
        "invisible": true
    },
    "type": "c8y_DynamicGroup",
    "name": " SmartGroupSendMessageXXX",
    "hajjMessage": "messages typed in the widget",
    "c8y_DeviceQueryString": "$filter=((id eq '**{{entered ID1}}**') or (id eq '**entered ID2**')) or (id eq '**entered ID3**'))"
}
console.log(obj)
postData('......url....', obj)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(postData)
        console.log(data);
    }); 
            </script>
```

I need "**or (id eq 'entered ID3'))**" to be added to the original text **$filter=((id eq '{{entered ID1}}')** if there more than one Id entered, based on the number of IDs, and to have each ID in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the IDs in an array, we can just format them then join them into the filter query

```
  function ButtonClicked(devicesIDs):
    var IDs = document.getElementById("devicesIDs").innerText;
    var inputArray = IDs.split(',');
    let filterGroup = inputArray.map(id => `(id eq '${id.trim()}')`)
    //  to choose one at random
    filterGroup = `$filter=(${filterGroup[Math.floor(Math.random()*filterGroup.length)]})`;
    // to use all with OR
    // filterGroup = `$filter=(${filterGroup.join(" or ")})`;
    
    let obj = {
      "c8y_isDynamicGroup": {
        "invisible": true
      },
      "type": "c8y_DynamicGroup",
      "name": " SmartGroupSendMessageXXX",
      "hajjMessage": "messages typed in the widget",
      "c8y_DeviceQueryString": filterGroup
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! is there also a way to choose only a one random id? I want to add a check box for (selecting only one of the entered list) so that when this is checked, it randomly only choose one id only and not all the list

Comment: I added in a way to pull a random filter. If this answer helped solve your question, please mark it as the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>{
  const IDs = document.getElementById("devicesIDs").value.split(','),
        obj = {
  "c8y_isDynamicGroup": {"invisible": true},
  "type": "c8y_DynamicGroup",
  "name": " SmartGroupSendMessageXXX",
  "hajjMessage": "messages typed in the widget",
  "c8y_DeviceQueryString": "$filter=("+IDs.map(id=>"(id eq '"+id.trim()+"')").join(" or ")+")"
  };
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/',  // placeholder for testing ...
   {method: 'POST',body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}})
 .then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))
}
```

```html
<p>Enter the IDs of devices seperated by comma</p>
<input id="devicesIDs" value="3,4,5">
<button>go</button>
```